Why does java.com still recommend Java 8, when there are multiple newer LTE releases?
I think I'm starting to understand this, but I was unable to find a satisfactory answer anywhere else and would love confirmation from someone with more java experience:
When I go to java.com to download the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), the latest version I can find there is Java 8, which was released 10 years ago and has already hit its "End of Public Updates" date.  There are 3 (soon to be 4) LTE releases that are newer than version 8, so why does java.com continue to recommend Java 8?  Where do I get the new LTE versions?
I'll post my hunch below, but I'd love confirmation or any corrections/clarifications!

from the download page of java.com: Why is Java 8 recommended? and "Version 8 Update 431 ... Release date: October 15, 2024"

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow

Reminder: Oracle is but one of several JDK/JRE vendors. Others include Azul Systems, Amazon, BellSoft, Microsoft, SAP, IBM, Red Hat, Adoptium of the Eclipse Foundation, and more. Tip: SDKMAN!.

Oracle's intention is that Java.com is the place where "end users" of Java should download Java JREs1.  Java 8 is the last official Oracle Java release that is aimed at end users; i.e. the last one that is available from Oracle2 as a JRE.  Ergo ...
For Java 9 and onward, Oracle doesn't want to be in the business of supporting end users.  Rather they want application developers to take on the task of providing Java as part of their application distribution and support.  Oracle's intention is that Java application developers and vendors should ship their applications with custom JREs created using the jlink and jpackager tools introduced with Java 9.
One point of evidence is in the Java.com Help pages, where you will find this:

Why should I download Java only from java.com?
There are only two sites where official downloads and updates for Java are provided by Oracle:

Java.com is recommended
Advanced users and developers may download from the Oracle Technology Network (OTN), where the Java Development Kit (JDK) is also available.



1 - My recollection is that Java.com was always aimed at end users.
2 - JREs for later Java releases and so on are available from other Java vendors.

This makes a lot of sense!  The main thing that tripped me up when trying to run software saying it couldn't find an appropriate version of java was that MacOS has a stub at /usr/bin/java that prints: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java."  And that's where it all started to go downhill... ;) Thanks!

Hmm ... I would say that this is the fault of the developers / vendors of the "software" for not providing a self-contained app; i.e. one with an embedded custom JRE.  Apple should take some of the blame for implementing that unhelpful stub.  (Or for not providing a package management system with packages for common / recent versions of Java.  Like Linux distros do.)

But also ... "end of public updates" for Java 8 actually refers to public releases under the old license arrangements.  People can still download newer versions (e.g. Java SE 8 Update 431 released on 2024-10-15) ... but they are subject to the OTN License Agreement.  (And it changed again in Java 17.)

Yeah, I guess I'm not sure whether apps like firebase-tools (the one I was trying to run) should be including a java runtime... it's a weird environment/scenario, because it's an npm package which, on-demand, will download and run some JAR files.  Kinda makes sense because it keeps the downloads/updates slim and it's in a developer environment where hopefully Java will already be installed... I just wish it mentioned the dependency somewhere, or had a better error message.  Thanks again for clarifications!

My Hunch:
After reading some obscure tidbits on The Java SE Support Roadmap, I believe the reason is that Java 9 launched with a "packaging" feature that allows developers to package an appropriate runtime with the application itself, making it a standalone application, which means for newer releases of Java, users no longer need to "install" the JRE before running an application (meaning java.com's "Download Java" page can disappear eventually).
Where this gets confusing is in the software development world, where a lot of java-dependent software might be offered for download without a packaged JRE, and then when it says to "install Java" you need to know how to get an appropriate, usually more recent, version of the JRE.
In this case, installing the Java Development Kit (JDK) is, as far as I can tell, the simplest way to download and install the latest JRE (since it is shipped with the JDK). For instance, on a mac: brew install openjdk.
In many cases, you need the JDK anyway, if you're trying to do development with a Java dependency (although I don't think that's true in all cases. AFAICT, firebase-tools just depends on the JRE, version 11+)
Is this correct? Am I making things up or misinterpreting? I don't know why this isn't better articulated anywhere else I could find. Hopefully this helps answer some questions for the next engineer who is confused by this.

wasn't that already posted in the question? (sure the end is slightly different) And "Is this correct?" is more a quesiton than an answer...

It was my question.  I moved this part to an answer just so users could vote/comment on this as an answer separately from the question.  Please feel free to post a better answer if you have one! :D
